# Views Accordion Closes When I Hit Next On Pager On Interior View

Tags: views, ajax, navigation

I have an issue where I have a [view accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) and each row on the accordion has a view with a pager.  When I hit next on the pager the accordion closes which is a very undesirable effect.  Any ideas?